# Is the Korban Pesach misnamed?

Tags: passover

Why is the lamb or kid used on Pesach called a Korban? 
None of its meat is burnt on the altar/mizbe’ach.
In what way is it a ‘sacrifice’?

Comment: -1 Parts of the Pesach offering are burnt on the alter. Such as the tail, its blood, etc.

Comment: More likely you are misinformed

Comment: I can understand why the OP is asking this question even though its based on ignorance of certain information. However, he seemed innocently asking us to understand this. Why would anyone downvote the question when someone is seeking knowledge? We should not discourage anyone who wants to learn just because they do not know something. It is not proper behavior to mass downvote this person's post IMHO.

Comment: Seeking knowledge is fine, however there are still criteria for a good question. A question based on erroneous unsourced assumptions is not a good question. The OP can improve this question by bringing sources or some basis for the assumptions. Questions that show effort are good questions.  See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/i-dont-think-were-explaining-sourcing-properly-to-new-users/1715#1715

Comment: @LN6595 the OP of the very post you link to says: "The problem is that comments like this feel combative and accusatory, without explaining to the new user what we're looking for. The user is instantly put on the defensive and gets the feeling that his participation is not welcome." This is not the Oxford debate club... laymen of all levels come here to ask for knowledge in a friendly manner. What did anyone here do (besides downvote a new user) to help the OP realize that they can improve the question?

Comment: @LN6595 How would you help the OP rephrase the question he needed an answer to, so that the question would be considered of acceptable quality?

Comment: @DavidKenner "Voting is at least - and probably more - important than commenting when it comes to improving the quality of the information presented by the site." https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/146/759 If someone can comment to, all the better. Bad question posts (not to be confused with bad questions) should be downvoted. In this case, the obvious thing he could do is remove all blatantly false information. (If there is information which he doesn't know if it is false or not, he should ask exactly that.)

Comment: For example “I've never heard of parts of the Korban Pesach being offered on the altar; I thought it was all eaten. So why is it called a Korban? Or was there indeed a part offered? [Which parts were those? Did any bones need to be broken to access those parts?]" (thank you DoubleAA) Adding some reasoning or research would justify the question.

Answer (score 9):

It is a sacrifice (*korban*) because some of the animal (a lamb or goat male in its first year) is offered on the altar. The Rambam writes (MT [Korban Pesach 1:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1062874/jewish/Korban-Pesach-Perek-1.htm))

> The blood of the Paschal sacrifice should be poured out on the base of
>   the altar. After the blood was poured, its belly should be opened up,
>   the fats and organs to be offered on the altar removed.

see also [1:14](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1062874/jewish/Korban-Pesach-Perek-1.htm).

For a very interesting description of the entire Korban Pesach process, see [here](http://dinonline.org/2012/03/26/the-korban-pesach/) from dinonline; the bottom section "Faster than a speeding bullet" has the information on the burning of some internal organs and fats.

PS. Maybe you meant to ask about the first Korban Pesach offered in Egypt since its organs couldn't be offered on a *mizbeach* that didn't exist then. The gemara in [Pesachim 96a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.96a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) answers that the door lintels of the Jewish homes were actually the altar (see also [here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=1369&article=5185)).

Answer (score 7):

"The blood of the Paschal sacrifice should be poured out on the base of the altar. After the blood was poured, its belly should be opened up, the fats and organs to be offered on the altar removed. The fats of each Paschal sacrifice should be offered on the pyre individually. The owner of the sacrifice should take his Paschal sacrifice with its hide to his home in Jerusalem.There he roasts it and eats it in the evening."

- Rambam Hilchos Korban Pesach 1:6

"If one set aside a female animal for his Paschal sacrifice or a male animal in its second or third year of life, it should be allowed to pasture until it contracts a disqualifying blemish. Then it should be sold and a Paschal sacrifice brought with the proceeds of the sale. **If it did not contract a blemish until after he offered his Paschal sacrifice, he should bring a peace-offering with the proceeds of the sale.**"

- Rambam Hilchos Korban Pesach 4:4

The Korban Pesach is learned from the Oral Law to belong to the Todah-Shelamim family of offerings (due to their similarities). As you can see from the second entry of Rambam above, the Passover is able to have its funds interchanged to a peace offering under certain circumstances.

For the procedures of the peace and thanks offerings see VaYikra 3 and 7: 11 - 18. The peace, thanks, and Passover offerings are all called "kodoshim kalim" (holy offerings of lesser sanctity) and share many aspects (and some differences of course).

I hope this helps. :-)